# Put a link into alert button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the JQuery plug-in Messi to display some alert boxes.

I want to go on the previous page when I click on the "Yes" button:

```
$('#yes-no-cancel-buttons').on('click', function() {
        new Messi('Voulez-vous vraiment annuler toutes les modifications effectuées ?', {title: 'Retour', modal:true, buttons: [{id: 0, label:
    'Yes',  val: 'Y', btnClass: 'btn-danger'}, {id: 1, label: 'No', val:
    'N', btnClass: 'btn-success'}, ]});     
 });
```

Unfortunately I just begin in Javascript and Jquery and don't really know how to do this.

Comment: I tried to put a data-rel="back" on the link but obviously, the alert would be useless with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply a `callback` property to options object:

```
new Messi('Voulez-vous vraiment annuler toutes les modifications effectuées ?',
    {
      title: 'Retour', modal: true,
      buttons: [
        {id: 0, label: 'Yes', val: 'Y', btnClass: 'btn-danger'},
        {id: 1, label: 'No', val: 'N', btnClass: 'btn-success'}],
      callback: function(val) { if(val == "Y") { history.back(); } }; }
    }
);
```

The callback function receives the value of the button clicked (in this case, either `'Y'` or `'N'`) as its first argument, and you can use a condition to decide whether to go back.

Comment: No problem. If you click the "Show/Hide code" on the [Messi examples page](http://marcosesperon.es/apps/messi/), you can see this behavior in the "Message with custom buttons (yes/no) and callback function" example.